# changing attributes of child elements using javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a simple button event that sets a class attribute that colors 100 `td` elements within 100 `<tr>` elements WHITE.  The elements are created in a canvas and set up to change the background color of the cells using a mouse-move event like a simple draw pad. I am unsure how to select every `<td>` element individually to set all their attributes back to white.  I realize this is possibly unorthodox and redundant but I need to know this for my own projects in the near future.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  #canvas { width: 500px;
            border: 3px dashed #989898;
    }
            .blue   { background-color: blue; }
            .white  { background-color: white; }
            td      { width: 3px; height: 3px; margin: 1px; padding: 1px; }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table id = "myCanvas">
     <caption>Draw Stuff Using Alt</caption>
     <tbody id = "tbody"></tbody>
  </table>
  <button onclick="rectify()">The CLEARANCE BUTTON</button>

<script>
function makeCanvas()
{
  var side = 100;

  var bodyA = document.getElementById( "tbody" );

   for ( var i = 0; i < side; ++i )
  {
     var row = document.createElement( "tr" );

     for ( var j = 0; j < side; ++j )
     {
        var cell = document.createElement( "td" );
        row.appendChild( cell );
     } 

    bodyA.appendChild( row );
  } 

document.getElementById( "myCanvas" ).addEventListener( 
  "mousemove", detectMouse, false );
}
//////////////////////////////This is the function in question
function rectify() 
{
   var side = 100;

   var row = document.getElementsByTagName( "tr" );

   var cell = document.getElementsByTagName( "td" );

   for ( var row = 0; i < side; ++i ){

      row.childNodes( cell ).target;

      for ( var j =0; j < side; ++i ){

          for ( var j = 0; j < side; ++i ){

          //if ( cell.attribute !== "white" ){

            cell.setAttribute( "class", "white" );

          //}
      }
    }
  }
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function detectMouse( a )
{        
   if ( a.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == "td" )
  {
     if ( a.altKey )
    {
     a.target.setAttribute( "class", "blue" );
    }
  } 
} 
  window.addEventListener( "load", makeCanvas, false );
  </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this with `document.querySelectorAll`. Yith this function you don't need nested loops. It just works with one loop because you can select all td elements there are inside a tr element.

```js
function makeCanvas() {
  var side = 100;
  var bodyA = document.getElementById( "tbody" );
  for ( var i = 0; i < side; ++i ) {
    var row = document.createElement( "tr" );
    for ( var j = 0; j < side; ++j ) {
      var cell = document.createElement( "td" );
      row.appendChild( cell );
    }
    bodyA.appendChild( row );
  }
  document.getElementById( "myCanvas" ).addEventListener("mousemove", detectMouse, false);
}
function rectify() {
  var side = 100;
  var cells = document.querySelectorAll('tr > td');
  for ( var cellNo = 0; cellNo < cells.length; cellNo++ ){
    cells[cellNo].setAttribute( "class", "white" );
  }
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function detectMouse( a ) {        
  if ( a.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == "td" ){
    if ( a.altKey ){
      a.target.setAttribute( "class", "blue" );
    }
  } 
} 
window.addEventListener( "load", makeCanvas, false );
```

```css
#canvas { width: 500px;
  border: 3px dashed #989898;
}
.blue   { background-color: blue; }
.white  { background-color: white; }
td      { width: 3px; height: 3px; margin: 1px; padding: 1px; }
```

```html
  <table id = "myCanvas">
     <caption>Draw Stuff Using Alt</caption>
     <tbody id = "tbody"></tbody>
  </table>
  <button onclick="rectify()">The CLEARANCE BUTTON</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear cut answer, if you don't mind my asking what is the significance of the `.querySelectorAll` parameters `'tr > td'`?  I'm not sure what it implies.

Comment: that is a [CSS Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors) string. In this case it means select all `td` elements that are direct children of `tr` elements.